# Is Go developed enough to use it to make the core of an operating system?

Tags: go

I'm wondering if Go is developed enough to use it to make the core of an operating system? So basically replace what you would normally use C for with Go.

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can develop an OS in almost any (Turing complete) language. Usually there's some small assembly layer required, though. And usually one must implement some parts of the OS using only a restricted subset of the language in question.

Examples:

- [JavaOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaOS).
- [Singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(operating_system)). (Applies with some limits only.)

What concerns Go, there used to be a usable (toy) Go kernel implementation, but it is now obsoleted already for a long time. From rsc's [post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/fS6Yg8o_cdQ/OPfkZHYPeQQJ):

> In the repository history there is a toy kernel called "tiny".
>   If you run hg log -k tiny you'll find it.  It doesn't build anymore
>   with the current version of Go but it illustrates what might
>   be done.  It had the whole package runtime, including the
>   garbage collector, in the kernel.
>
> Russ

Comment: Also some good discussion at http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?t=25089 and, not sure if it's serious, https://code.google.com/p/gofy/ but it hasn't seen any updates for a couple of years.

Comment: But could you make a full fledge operating system with go?

Comment: @user2450516: With the reservation of "some assembly required/unavoidable", yes.